# Dual monitor doesn't work on DisplayPort

Tags: kali-linux, monitors, hdmi, displayport

At first, I thought I had an issue with connecting the second monitor.
But I found out that connecting to the second monitor is working through HDMI.  
It is only the DisplayPort that doesn't work.

Someone knows why could this be?

I'm running Linux kali 5.3.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.3.15-1kali1 (2019-12-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux.

GPUs: (`lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"`)

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530
>   (rev 06) 
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M
>   [GeForce GTX 970M] (rev a1)

Comment: could be bad DisplayPort

Comment: This is likely a hardware ***compatibility*** issue, not a plain hardware issue. If you want to increase the chances of your question attracting attention, include all the hardware info + kernel version + loaded kernel module info related to your box and its discrete graphic card, if any.

Comment: @jsotola It's not a bad Display port, I have a dual boot with Windows 10 where the monitor works fine, so it has to be a software issue.

Comment: @Cbhihe I've added some more info about my Linux version and GPUs to the question.